# I have just tried to print out pressed keys with the keyboard module

Tags: python

I have just tried to print out pressed keys with the keyboard module. It also works, but there are weird keyboard events and I want to get rid this.

```
import keyboard

recorded = keyboard.record(until='esc')
recorded = str(recorded)
print(recorded)
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the output as text.

Comment: The "*weird keyboard events*" are the `KeyboardEvent` objects that your `keyboard` library recorded. This class' properties are documented on the [project's GitHub homepage](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#class-keyboardkeyboardevent). Why not loop the elements of this list and extract the `name` property, if that's what you want? Why do you want to get rid of the objects in this list that contain the data you're after?

Comment: @esqew yeah thats what I want to do but idk how to do that

Comment: @user_na I did in the enter image description if you mean that

Comment: @Halby While you've gotten an answer below, accessing properties of an object is a pretty foundational Python concept; if doing this gives you trouble I would recommend re-visiting some more foundational literature on [Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) - it will help your understanding immensely.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the source code](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/0ef92be1507be91987d4c2dad46f739492ccb9d8/keyboard/__init__.py#L1138), `keyboard.record()` returns a list of `KeyboardEvent` objects. Their [`__repr__` function](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/_keyboard_event.py#L41) adds the `KeyboardEvent()` text, but it displays the key and its state via `self.name` and `self.event_type`. So, your code could display just the key and event type via:

```
import keyboard

recorded = keyboard.record(until='esc')
for key in recorded:
    print(f"{key.name} {key.event_type}")
```

If you don't want the code to output the event type, e.g. `p up` and `p down`, you can do the following:

```
import keyboard

recorded = keyboard.record(until='esc')
for key in recorded:
    if key.event_type == 'down': #only output key presses, not key releases
        print(key.name)
```

Comment: and now I want to get rid of down and up because if you run this code the output is "p down" and then "p up"

Comment: I'll update my answer to show how you could do that.

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if you have any questions.